# How to redirect when accessing a url path ending in .gif to main page via .htacess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

hello i'm breaking my head to resolve i wish that when the user accesses for example mysite.com/file.gif it will be redirected to mysite.com how can i do this for any file ending in .gif? via htaccess;

any help is welcome.
thanks in advance

In short I want my user to only redirect if the user enters the final url example mysite.com/upload/file.gif

the way i am doing it does not display the images externally for example image of banners external logos the image does not appear. does anyone know how to fix?
with this current change. images are broken, I just need to redirect the user to mysite main page. without breaking the image files.

my actual .htacess file

```
    RewriteEngine on

# if the query string contains a parameter called "lang"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)fbclid=
# then redirect (permanently) to /
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=permanent]

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.*\.gif$ https://mysite,com/ [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value engine off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value engine off
</IfModule>

<Files ~ "\.((php[0-9]?)|p?html?|pl|sh|java|cpp|c|h|js|rc)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Of course these images will be broken, when you redirect to your root URL, and that root URL does _not_ return an image itself. _“when the user accesses for example mysite.com/file.gif”_ - yeah, that’s what they - resp. their browser - did, when that image URL was embedded somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can't find a rule that does only redirect dir. I thought about it and think that only the redirect and not the segmentation of the file extension. The problem is that I can’t find anything on the internet so I can do just a redirect. Can you help me?

Comment: Not sure what you mean now, _“I can't find a rule that does only redirect dir”_?

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution for hours, I tried several and none were successful :(

Comment: @CBroe you would know to inform me. where I can find a rule for it to work. I'm a layman and I'm having a hard time.

Comment: No, I can not help you, when your response to being told that I don’t understand what you mean now, is not a proper explanation, but you just go on about how you tried stuff and weren’t successful.